# Make marker-end same color as path?

Tags: svg

The path has a certain `stroke` color which may change programatically. Can the marker's `fill` also be the exact same as the path's stroke color? (I'll use javascript for this if I have to.)

Comment: see here: [color the arrow heads same as the associated line](https://github.com/sverweij/mscgen_js/issues/13)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Markers are independent from the paths they are applied to and don't inherit colours. Nor is there a way to automatically have their colours match the path.

You will have to set their colour explicitly.

Comment: Is there a way to set the color of a marker programmatically then? Or do I have to create a different marker for every single color I want to use?

Comment: If the marker has an `id` then you can change the color like `myMarker.setAttribute('fill','blue');` or jQuery `$('#myMarker').attr('fill','blue');` ...or you could create the complete marker elements individually and append the HTML to the SVG element's innerHTML.

Answer (score 2):

IE and Firefox render markers color inherited from path, but Chrome does not.

I think it's a chrome bug.

Comment: I think this is no longer the case. Chrome does not inherit colors anymore (2018 Chrome 69)

Comment: Firefox doesn't either.