# How to apply a gradient to a marker?

Tags: svg, gradient, marker

In SVG, how to apply the gradient applied to a line to its marker-end  ?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone="yes"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="820px"
     height="500px"
     viewBox="0 0 820 500"
     version="1.1" >
  <style>
    .axis3 {
         stroke-width: 40px;
         marker-end:url(#arrow);
         stroke: url('#gradient_3');
         fill: url('#gradient_3');
         height: 30px;
    }
    .axis4 {
         stroke-width: 40px;
         marker-end:url(#arrow);
         stroke: url('#gradient_4');
         fill: url('#gradient_4'); /* corrected */
         height: 30px;
    }
  </style>
  <defs>
    <marker
       id="arrow"
       markerWidth="20"
       markerHeight="40"
       refX="0"
       refY="20"
       orient="auto"
       markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       style="fill:inherit;">
      <path style="stroke:none;fill:inherit;overflow:visible;" d="M0 0 L20 20 L0 40 Z" />
    </marker>

    <linearGradient id="gradient_3" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="yellow" />
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="gradient_4" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="blue" />
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="green" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <line class="axis3" x1="50" x2="400" y1="50" y2="50" />
  <line class="axis4" x1="50" x2="400" y1="100" y2="100" />
</svg>
```

With the code above, marker is always black.

As there are several elements line with different gradients, gradient can not be applied directly on the path.
I tried to add style="fill:inherit" - with no success.

Comment: Vivaldi and Chrome don't natively apply gradient on marker-end.
Internet Explorer natively apply gradient on marker-end - except that it's the rendring is the one expected on a marker-start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to "[Make marker-end same color as path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060391/make-marker-end-same-color-as-path)" mentions that there is no inheritance of colors from related path.
Situation has not evolve since this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

Instead of `fill:inherit;` I'm setting two css variables for the svg element: `style="--fill:url(#gradient_3); --stroke:url(#gradient_4)"`. Both the line and the marker are using those variables for the `fill` and the `stroke`.

Alternatively you may choose to use the gradients directly in the code `<path style="overflow:visible;fill:url(#gradient_3);"...`

To your code I've added a `#gradient_3` since you are using it.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="820px"
     height="500px"
     viewBox="0 0 820 500"
     version="1.1"  
     style="--fill:url(#gradient_3); --stroke:url(#gradient_4)">
  <style>
    .axis {
         stroke-width: 40px;
         marker-end:url(#arrow);
         height: 30px;
         stroke:var(--stroke);
    }
  </style>
  <defs>
    <marker
       id="arrow"
       markerWidth="20"
       markerHeight="40"
       refX="0"
       refY="20"
       orient="auto"
       markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path style="overflow:visible;fill:var(--fill);" d="M0 0 L20 20 L0 40 Z" />
    </marker>
    <linearGradient id="gradient_3" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="green" />
      <stop offset="20%"  stop-color="blue" /> 
    </linearGradient>

    <linearGradient id="gradient_4" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="blue" />
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="green" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <line class="axis" x1="50" x2="400" y1="50" y2="50" />
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback : I have clarified my need.